# Minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

1. Let  be a vector space over the field  and  be a linear operator
   on . Then all eigen values of  are zeros of the minimal polynomial of .
2. Minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial.

**Qus:** If every zero of char. polynomial is a zero of minimal polynomial then how can minimal polynomial divide char. polynomial?

**Note-** A minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $T$ is the monic polynomial with least degree s.t $m(T)=O$. Since $m(x)$ is of least degree, then how can it contain every zero of char. polynomial?

Comment: $(x-2)(x-3)$ divides $(x-2)(x-2)(x-2)(x-3)(x-3)$

Comment: @user3257842 so a minimal polynomial contains only non-repeated zeros?

Comment: Not necessarily . But the roots it contains are of lesser then or equal multiplicity than those of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Got it!!... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $I_{3\times 3}$, characteristic polynomial is $p(x)=(x-1)^3$ while minimal polynomial is $m(x)=(x-1)$. Both polynomials have zeros at $x=1$ (eigenvalue of $I$), though the only possible difference is in their orders where it may be more for $p(x)$ than that of $m(x)$.